# jQuery Animation on multiple items

Tags: jquery

On the page i have multiple thumbs images, each has it's own id, generated by php.

I need to do the jQuery animation for each element.

I'm stuck here, how i can detect witch `thumb_id-??` the user is hovering, and animate it?

I know i can do two simple js function for onmouseover/out and pass the id.. but there is another method of doing it with jQuery?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumb_id- ??? ').mouseover(function(){
                div = $('div.thumb-img-hover');
                div.animate({opacity: '1'}, 150);
    }).mouseout(function(){
                div.animate({opacity: '0'}, 150);
    });
});
</script>
```

---

```
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo '  
    <a class="group1" text="TESTING" title="" href="'.$baseurl.'uploads/'.$val["filename"].'">
    <div class="thumb-img-container right">
    <div class="thumb-img" style="position:relative;background:url(\''.$baseurl.'uploads/thumbs/'.$val["filename"].'\') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;">
    <div id="thumb_id-'.$val["id"].'" class="thumb-img-hover"><a href="'.$baseurl.'index.php?action=image&id='.$val["id"].'">test</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Why not using class selector?

Comment: Give all the thumbs a class and use the class selector: `$('.thumb_class')`.

Comment: I tried, But if i hover on a item. All items get the animation, not only the one that i'm hovering.

Comment: Unless you need them for other purposes, you don't need ids. Just attach handler(s) to a jquery collection selected by class, and inside the handler(s), address the hovered element as `this` (or `$(this)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute starts with selector, `$('div[id^=thumb_id]')`, but why not using class selector?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.thumb-img-hover').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, 150); // this refers to the current element
    }).mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({opacity: '0'}, 150);
    });
});
```

You can also use CSS:

```
div.thumb-img-hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 150ms;  
   -moz-transition: opacity 150ms; 
   -o-transition: opacity 150ms;  
   transition: opacity 150ms;
}
div.thumb-img-hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm facing a little problem.. As you can see there is a link inside the DIV, When mouseovering on the DIV and then on the link, the animation start again. How i can stop that?

Comment: @DjRikyx That's because your are using `mouseover`, use `mouseenter/mouseleave` instead. I have updated the answer.